# Lightbox and dynamic PDF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, lightbox, fpdf

I would like to open a lightbox frame with a PDF file inside.

I am already able to do it by using `data-lightbox="iframe"` and the pdf filename as `href` tag.

The main problem is that i modify this PDF file on the fly (by FPDF/FPDFI) and i need to pass an array from `jQuery` to PHP PDF generation page.

When I push the "Generate" button on the page, i populate the array and next i send it by `$.ajax` POST with the array as data, but i don't know how to show it straight back to lightbox without saving it on the webserver

I don't know the method i should use to solve this problem

```
$('.generate').on('click', function(e) {
    var data = [];
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input').each(function(el) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('bt-switch')) {
            tempval = $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');
        } else {
            tempval = $(this).val();
        }
        data.push(tempval);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "function.php?act=gen",
        data: {
            arr: data
        },
        success: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide example code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done. Obviously the php page take this array and give back ($pdf->Output()) a PDF with the right values set

Comment: Could you add the answer to your question and choose that one as the answer within a couple of days? So your question can be closed. Well done!

Comment: I meant "done" by providing example code... :D

Comment: I ended up in the same way of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38393253/1312611

Comment: I will answer tomorrow!